# What is this PIP syntax: "azureml-dataset-runtime[pandas,fuse]"

Tags: python, pip

I came recently across this environment file:

```yaml
name: azureml_mnist
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - ipykernel=5.5.3
  - matplotlib=3.4.1
  - python=3.8
  - pip  
  - pip:
    - azureml-dataset-runtime[pandas,fuse]
```

Regarding this line:
`azureml-dataset-runtime[pandas,fuse]`

What do the square brackets mean? I've never seen packages declared like this and could not find anything in the docs to explain what this [ ] syntax means or does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, you can check several answeres here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775346/what-do-square-brackets-mean-in-pip-install

So, `[]` denotes extra packages that should be installed together with `azureml-dataset-runtime`

Here is a link where you can check other extra packages required:

https://www.wheelodex.org/projects/azureml-dataset-runtime/